# Slim error about `Unexpected data in output buffer` not related to characters before a PHP tag or a closing PHP tag

Tags: php, apache, rest, api, slim

I have this simple code structure:

api.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'api/Main.class.php';
    new Main();
```

api/Main.class.php:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '../../vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once 'Router/Router.class.php';

    class Main
    {

        function __construct()
        {
            $router = new Router();
            $router->getRoute();
        }

    }
```

Router/Router.class.php:

```
<?php
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    require_once __DIR__.'../../../vendor/autoload.php';

    class Router
    {

        function getRoute()
        {
            $app = new \Slim\App;

            $app->get(
                '/',
                function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
                    $response->getBody()->write('Home');

                    return $response;
                }
            );

            $app->run();
        }

    }
```

This produces the following error when I go to `api.php`: `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unexpected data in output buffer. Maybe you have characters before an opening &lt;?php tag? in /Path/to/project/root/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php:625`

This error doesn't give me much information. I've been trying to get Slim to work in an OOP codebase, but this error keeps popping up every time I try this.

I've also tried returning `$app`, so I can run t elsewhere, which also produces the same error. What is going wrong in this code?

Comment: Did you check your files to make sure there are no extra characters (event a single space) before `<?php` tags?

Comment: @Nima Yes, as mentioned in the question title, I already checked that

Comment: If you have written any custom php file with php ending tag , remove it . It should work. 

"If a file contains only PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script."
Ref : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php